# subdivide intersected faces in three js

Tags: javascript, model, geometry, intersection

I created this javascript code to subdivide the intersected face from the loaded mesh :

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
{
    console.log("Click.");
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {

var smooth = THREE.GeometryUtils.clone( intersects[0].object.geometry );

var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(1);

modifier.modify( smooth );

intersects[0].object.geometry = smooth;

}
```

But the code subdivide the totality of the mesh.
can you help me.
Thank you

Comment: Help you with what? Please ask a specific question

Comment: how subdivide selected faces in existed model (the model is loaded)